# my "Yahtzee" code sometimes throws in a random number

Tags: java, math

Alright so basically I wanted to make a code that would generate numbers until it hit a perfect "Yahtzee" first try. Sometimes it doesn't work and I'm pretty new to coding (which is why this is an abomination) and even newer to SO. I did this just for education but I don't understand why it sometimes doesn't work. About 20% of the time, instead of saying "11111" it will say "11114" randomly. Help me out?

```
public class IDontKnowWhatImDoing {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int min = 1;
    int max = 6;
    
    int randomInt1 = (int)(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
    int randomInt2 = (int)(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
    int randomInt3 = (int)(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
    int randomInt4 = (int)(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
    int randomInt5 = (int)(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
    while(randomInt1 != randomInt2) {
        randomInt1 = (int)(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
        randomInt2 = (int)(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
        randomInt3 = (int)(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
        randomInt4 = (int)(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
        randomInt5 = (int)(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
        System.out.println(randomInt1);
        System.out.println(randomInt2);
        System.out.println(randomInt3);
        System.out.println(randomInt4);
        System.out.println(randomInt5);
        System.out.println();
        while(randomInt2 != randomInt3) {
            randomInt1 = (int)(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
            randomInt2 = (int)(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
            randomInt3 = (int)(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
            randomInt4 = (int)(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
            randomInt5 = (int)(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
            System.out.println(randomInt1);
            System.out.println(randomInt2);
            System.out.println(randomInt3);
            System.out.println(randomInt4);
            System.out.println(randomInt5);
            System.out.println();
            while(randomInt3 != randomInt4) {
                randomInt1 = (int)(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
                randomInt2 = (int)(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
                randomInt3 = (int)(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
                randomInt4 = (int)(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
                randomInt5 = (int)(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
                System.out.println(randomInt1);
                System.out.println(randomInt2);
                System.out.println(randomInt3);
                System.out.println(randomInt4);
                System.out.println(randomInt5);
                System.out.println();
                while(randomInt4 != randomInt5) {
                    randomInt1 = (int)(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
                    randomInt2 = (int)(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
                    randomInt3 = (int)(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
                    randomInt4 = (int)(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
                    randomInt5 = (int)(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
                    System.out.println(randomInt1);
                    System.out.println(randomInt2);
                    System.out.println(randomInt3);
                    System.out.println(randomInt4);
                    System.out.println(randomInt5);
                    System.out.println();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Since you're pretty new to coding, you need to learn about methods.  The Oracle tutorial, [Learning the Java Language](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html) will take you through Java step-by-step.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the conditions you use to check whether you have a five of the same number. If a certain condition is already false (the numbers match), you don't enter that look.

For example, if you randomly generate five numbers, where the first two happen to be equal, then `randomInt1 != randomInt2` will be false.
You will then never enter the `while(randomInt1 != randomInt2)` block, and exit with that initial set of numbers, even though you've only checked that the first two are equal, not the other 3. This problem is present at each level of your nested loops.

---

The direct solution would be to use `do-while` loops instead (and removing the first number generator block). This allows each pair of numbers to actually be checked at least once.

---

That is however an inelegant solution. Assuming that you still want to generate five numbers each time (as in Yahtzee, instead of something simpler like generating one die at a time), it would be cleaner to have a single `do-while` loop. In that, you could have a single block of random number calls instead of redundant ones at different nesting levels. The condition would have it continue looping until all 5 are equal.

Answer (score 1):

You really don't need all that repetitious code. It all boils down to the condition you use for your `while` loop. You already know that you need 5 of a kind for a Yahtzee and that means that all dice must match the first dice that is rolled so, your `while` loop
condition can be:

```
while ((randomInt1 != randomInt2) || (randomInt1 != randomInt3) || 
            (randomInt1 != randomInt4) || (randomInt1 != randomInt5)) {
    // ........ other code ....
}
```

This condition keeps the loop running until all dice are of the same value. With this in mind, you can reduce your code to:

```
int min = 1;
int max = 6;

int randomInt1 = 1;
int randomInt2 = 2;
int randomInt3 = 3;
int randomInt4 = 4;
int randomInt5 = 5;
while ((randomInt1 != randomInt2) || (randomInt1 != randomInt3) || 
        (randomInt1 != randomInt4) || (randomInt1 != randomInt5)) {
    randomInt1 = (int) (Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
    randomInt2 = (int) (Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
    randomInt3 = (int) (Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
    randomInt4 = (int) (Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
    randomInt5 = (int) (Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
    System.out.print(randomInt1 + " " + randomInt2 + " " +  
                     randomInt3 + " " +  randomInt4 + " " +  randomInt5);
    System.out.println();
}
System.out.println(" YAHTZEE");
```

You can however reduce more repetitious code. You really only need one random number generator. By making your dice an **array** of dice, for example:

```
int[] dice = new int[5];
boolean yahtzee = false;
while (!yahtzee) {
    int count = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < dice.length; i++) {
        dice[i] = (int) (Math.random() * (6 - 1 + 1) + 1);
        if (i > 0 && dice[i] == dice[i-1]) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    if (count == 5) { 
        yahtzee = true; 
    }
}

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(dice) + "  YAHTZEE!!");
```

Another way might be by making use of a **HashSet** since a HashSet will only hold ***distinct*** values, for example:

```
Integer[] dice = new Integer[5];
java.util.Set<Integer> s = new java.util.HashSet<>();

// If all elements are same, size of HashSet should be 1. 
// since the HashSet contains only 'distinct' values. 
while (s.size() != 1) {
    for (int i = 0; i < dice.length; i++) {
        dice[i] = (int) (Math.random() * (6 - 1 + 1) + 1);
    }
    // Put all array elements in a HashSet
    s = new java.util.HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(dice));
}

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(dice) + "   YAHTZEE!!");
```

Comment: Thank you guys for the help. I learned a lot!